# Redundant Rows from Case Statement and Join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am getting some duplicates with my case statement.

How to avoid this without using subqueries?

```
SELECT  

  [S].[TicketNbr] AS 'Ticket Nbr'
, [S].[status_description] AS 'Status'
, ( CASE  WHEN [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk' THEN 1  ELSE 0  END) AS 'Moved from Old Board?' END) AS 'Moved from Old Board?'

FROM [Service] AS [S]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Audit] AS [A]   
ON [A].[TicketNbr]=[S].[TicketNbr]

GROUP BY [S].[TicketNbr]
, [S].[status_description]
,(CASE  WHEN [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk' THEN 1  ELSE 0  END)
```

Note I only want the row with 1.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you should be using an outer join here? What are you trying to do with this query?

Answer (score 1):

Those are not duplicates, they're separate records resulting from multiple rows in `Audit` - in your example one with `OldValue_Text` of 'Service Desk' and one which is not.

Now, if you're only looking for the `1` when present and `0` otherwise, you could do one of three things:

1. Keep your existing query and take the max of your third column:

   ```
   SELECT      
     [S].[TicketNbr] AS [Ticket Nbr],
     [S].[status_description] AS [Status],
     MAX((CASE WHEN [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END)) AS [Moved from Old Board?]

   FROM [Service] AS [S]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [Audit] AS [A]   
     ON [A].[TicketNbr]=[S].[TicketNbr]

   GROUP BY [S].[TicketNbr],
     [S].[status_description]
   ```
2. Use `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery (I know you say you don't want to use one, but this is a valid solution):

   ```
   SELECT      
     [S].[TicketNbr] AS [Ticket Nbr],
     [S].[status_description] AS [Status],
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Audit] AS [A]   
       WHERE [A].[TicketNbr]=[S].[TicketNbr]
       AND [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Moved from Old Board?]

   FROM [Service] AS [S]
   ```
3. Add the criteria `OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk'` to the join clause instead. This will reduce the joined rows to the ones you are after. (Note this assumes there is only one row that matches; if not you may have to add `DISTINCT`):

   ```
   SELECT      
     [S].[TicketNbr] AS [Ticket Nbr],
     [S].[status_description] AS [Status],
     CASE WHEN [A].[TicketNbr] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Moved from Old Board?]

   FROM [Service] AS [S]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [Audit] AS [A]   
     ON [A].[TicketNbr]=[S].[TicketNbr]
     AND [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk'
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for listing multiple options!

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement is in the select clause, so it isn't giving you duplicates. Also these aren't duplicates, they are completely different records. I believe all you will need to do is add a where clause that only pulls records with OldValue_Text of 'Service Desk'

```
WHERE [A].OldValue_Text LIKE 'Service Desk'
```

You would add this after your from clause but before your group by clause.

This will reduce your result set to only the items that have a value of 1 for `Moved from old Board?`

If this gives you duplicates, then you can just add a `distinct` to your select clause

```
SELECT  DISTINCT

      [S].[TicketNbr] AS 'Ticket Nbr'
    , [S].[status_description] AS 'Status'
    , ( CASE  WHEN [A].OldValue_Text = 'Service Desk' THEN 1  ELSE 0  END) AS 'Moved from Old Board?' END) AS 'Moved from Old Board?'
```